# Tridion - Event System Objects are Not Being Destroyed

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have created a `TcmExtension` named `WorkflowEventSystem` that has an event handler subscribed to the `FinishProcess` event.  The purpose of this event is to schedule for publish all dependencies (i.e. pages) of the associated workflow subject.

The problem I am having is that even though the event triggers at the right time (a workflow process is completed), and all the items that are supposed to be scheduled for publish are, the `PublishScheduler` object created by the event never seems to go out of scope, and as such the WorkflowEventSystem object does not either.

Is there something I am missing about how the Event System works that would cause these objects to live on forever?  I've included what I consider the relevant code below (some parts summarized).  Thanks for any help.

Here's most of the actual TcmExtension:

```cs
public class WorkflowEventSystem : TcmExtension
{
    public WorkflowEventSystem()
    {
        this.Subscribe();
    }

    public void Subscribe()
    {
        EventSystem.Subscribe<ProcessInstance, FinishProcessEventArgs>(ScheduleForPublish, EventPhases.All);
    }
}
```

`ScheduleForPublish` creates a `PublishScheduler` object (class I created):

```cs
private void ScheduleForPublish(ProcessInstance process, FinishProcessEventArgs e, EventPhases phase)
{
    if(phase == EventPhases.TransactionCommitted)
    {
        PublishScheduler publishScheduler = new PublishScheduler(process);
        publishScheduler.ScheduleForPublish(process);
        publishScheduler = null;  // worth a try
    }
}
```

The `ScheduleForPublish` method looks similar to this:

```cs
public void ScheduleForPublish(ProcessInstance process)
{
    using(Session session = new Session("ImpersonationUser"))
    {
        var publishInstruction = new PublishInstruction(session);
        // Set up some publish Instructions

       var publicationTargets = new List<PublicationTarget>();
       // Add a PublicationTarget here by tcm id

       IList<VersionedItem> itemsToPublish = new List<VersionedItem>();
       // Add the items we want to publish by calling GetUsingItems(filter)
       // on the workflow process' subject

       //Publish the items
       PublishEngine.Publish(itemsToPublish.Cast<IdentifiableObject>(), publishInstruction, publishTargets);
    }    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say the PublishScheduler object does not go out of scope? How can you tell?

Comment: @Quirijn PublishScheduler is just a class I created, to take most of the logic out of the actual TcmExtension.  All it contains is the ScheduleForPublish method and some helper classes, you can see the meat of it in the last code example I have included here.

Comment: Quirijn's question is crucial. How can you tell you have a problem? What are the symptoms? How are you able to monitor it?

Comment: @DominicCronin sorry I misread his question at first, I first noticed this when an instance collection was retaining its values across separate occurrences of the event (at first I had all logic just in the WorkflowEventSystem).  I confirmed by placing a line of code in a destructor for each class to write an entry to the event log upon destruction.  The destructor entries never appear in the event log unless I shut the Tridion COM+ service down. The last thing each class' method does is write a 'Done' entry to the event log, those entries do appear, they just never seems to be destroyed.

Comment: Also, I am assuming this is related, but I receive the following Warning three times in a row in the 'Tridion Content Manager' event log whenever I start the COM+ Service: Event 200, Kernel: Unable to create an Event System Object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Life-cycle management for `TcmExtension` classes is quite simple:

1. when you call `Subscribe` the `TcmExtension` object you specify is added to an internal list of subscriptions
2. when you later call `Unsubscribe` the same `TcmExtension` object is removed from the list of subscriptions

Since you never call `Unsubscribe` your `WorkflowEventSystem` is never removed and thus will never be garbage collected by .NET. And since your `WorkflowEventSystem` holds a reference to the `PublishScheduler` instance it created, that one will thus also never be cleaned up.

The proper boilerplate for a custom `TcmExtension` is:

```cs
public class WorkflowEventSystem : TcmExtension, IDisposable
{
    EventSubscription _subscription;

    public WorkflowEventSystem()
    {
        this.Subscribe();
    }

    public void Subscribe()
    {
         _subscription = EventSystem.Subscribe<ProcessInstance, 
             FinishProcessEventArgs>(ScheduleForPublish, EventPhases.All);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _subscription.Unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Nuno also gave a longer example (handling multiple subscribers) in this article: 
http://nunolinhares.blogspot.nl/2012/07/validating-content-on-save-part-1-of.html

Comment: Aren't you missing an underscore before 'subscription' inside the Subscribe method?